# Check for multiple array indexes in react/typescript, whether one exists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
if(inputData.info[0].instruction){
  return (
  <Text ref={instructionContainerRef} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ 
    __html: replaceTextLinks(inputData.info[0].instruction) 
    }}>
  </Text>
)
  }
  else {
    return null
  }
```

So the possible index positions for the inputData.info] index are 0-68. How can I achieve to check whether there exists data for an array index between 0-68, and if it finds one than then to return the if statement with this array index?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about:

```js
function checkItems(info, length) {
  return Array
    .from(Array(length).keys())
    .map((_, i) => info[i] && info[i].instruction)
    .filter(item => item).length === length;
}

let index = 14;

return checkItems(inputData.info, 68) ?
  <Text ref={instructionContainerRef} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ 
  __html: replaceTextLinks(inputData.info[index].instruction) 
  }}> :
  null;
```

Comment: And how could I check for let index 0-68 here?

Comment: Just updated my answer. I didn't get the question right the first time. So, you want to see if there are 68 valid items in the array and then render?

Comment: What about? replaceTextLinks(inputData.info[index].instruction), it shouldnt stay the same, should it?

Comment: No I would like to see if there is one valid item among these 68 items, and if there is one then render this one

Comment: The `checkItems` function does exactly that. I mean it checks if the a number of items in the passed array are truthy.

Comment: Yeah I get you, but there is still replaceTextLinks(inputData.info[index].instruction)  & let index = 14 in the code, is that correct?

Comment: Hm ... I don't understand how is this relevant to the question that you are asking. By the time you reach that point you already validated that the item exists.

Comment: Ah look, I meant that I would like to test out different values for index, so test it with index 0 if it's undefined, test it with 2, then with 3, because index is not defined by myself but by the database.

Comment: The index could be a value between 0-68, but I don't exactly know which one it is, so I am not defining it myself

Comment: That's exactly why I wrote `checkItems(inputData.info, 68)`. This function accepts an array and checks if all the items from 0 to 68 are there (truthy).

Answer (score 0):

`inputData.info.find(inf => !!inf)` will return the first object that is not null or undefined.